# How can I make text flow from one column to another if the column becomes full? I illustrated it if the question doesn’t make sense. Thank you

Tags: html, css

I want text to automatically go from the left column to the right column once it gets full. Thank you for your help, I am a beginner.
For example:

```
       rhjssjskdjdjdkdjdj.         Rhejejejejejejejdj
      ehshsjskejekemek.         Hrjejejesusjejsjs
      aososskskskksskk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first set the CSS property **column-count** to specify the number of columns you need. The default behavior is to balance the amount of text in all the columns. However, if you specify a **height** on your container and then use the CSS **column-fill** property and set this to **auto**, the text will only go to subsequent columns once it reaches the container's height. You will need to play around with the height of your container to get the effect you're looking for.

```css
.columns {
  height: 220px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
  ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue
  duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem.
  Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
</div>
```